# Python Pywin & OneNote COM: OneNote.Application.15 'cannot automate the makepy process'

Tags: python, winapi, com, onenote

I'm interacting with OneNote's COM interop using Python on Win32.

Here's the most basic code to pull out notebook hierarchy:

```
import win32com.client
onObj = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('OneNote.Application.12')
result = onObj.GetHierarchy("",win32com.client.constants.hsNotebooks)
print(result)
```

Note the `OneNote.Application.12`, this works as I'd expect.

The thing is that when I run Makepy I'm actually selecting the v15 type library:

[image]

If I change the code to be either `OneNote.Application.15` or just `OneNote.Application` then I get an error:

```
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object
```

Why is this please? I'm running:

- Python 3.3.1 (64bit)
- Pywin build 218 (AMD64)
- Win 8 x64
- Office 2013 x64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your registry record, in particular key {0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725} in TypeLib section:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725}

This strange bevahior is probably caused by existence of invalid subkeys. This class key have to contain only a single subkey "1.1" and nothing else.

The correct registry record for this class should look as follows:

```
|- {0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725}
|     |- 1.1
|         |-0
|         | |- win32
|         |- FLAGDS
|         |- HELPDIR
```

The key "win32" have to point to OneNote executable, e.g. C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office15\ONENOTE.EXE\3

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've been trying on-and-off for months trying to get this to work, and finally a combination of your answer, and the [onepy](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py) library has resulted in successful communication with OneNote 2013 from Python!

Comment: Brilliant works for me too. I deleted the 1.0 branch and ran the above code and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned here: [onepy](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py).. Install Python 3.4 x86 from here
Install PyWin32 for Python 3.4 x86 from here
Add C:\Python34\ to your PATH variable
Run C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\makepy.py
Select Microsoft OneNote 15.0 Extended Type Library...  and also updated the registry to delete the extra 1.0 folder like explained above and retained the 1.1 along with its subfolder content. But still facing the same issue at OP. Any other tips or tricks involved here? Appreciate a detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Zdenek do you know the registry for Excel? I've ben facing the same problem for Microsoft Office Program.

I tried to look at 'regedit' which KEY could work but I am not sure of.

Answer (score 1):

In `site-packages\win32com\` there was a folder `F2A7EE29-8BF6-4A6D-83F1-098E366C709Cx0x1x0`, this contained the v12 type library. There was also a file `0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725x0x1x1.py` which looks like the v15 lib.

Changing my code to:

```
gencache.EnsureModule('{0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725}', 0, 1, 1)
onapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('OneNote.Application.15')
```

I get access to the v15 type library. I'm still not clear why it requires this explicit reference, though.

Comment: Would you mind posting your entire script? Or at least enough that works with `win32com.client.Dispatch('OneNote.Application.15')` and `onapp.GetHierarchy`? I tried what you posted with just `import win32com.client` before it and `onapp.GetHierarchy()` doesn't work for me. Edit: just realized this is 10 years old...hmm